# Extracting the web technologies used in a website

Tags: internet

I am looking for a program (not a web service like http://builtwith.com or http://w3techs.com/) that can provide an overview of web technologies used in a given website.

- Input: website URL, e.g. http://www.ebay.com/
- Output: web technologies, e.g. Server-side Programming Language, Client-side Programming Language, Web Server, Advertising Networks, Analytics and Tracking, JavaScript Libraries, Content Delivery Network, Encoding, etc. [Example 1](http://builtwith.com/ebay.com); [Example 2](http://w3techs.com/sites/info/ebay.com).

If possible, free, open-source, CLI, Windows 7 or Linux.